# Get an image to fill to end of div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to get .c5 to take up the remaining space of the div. Just so it looks better then having a blank space and the remaining space will vary depending on the device so it cant be a set width. You can see it working here www[dot]techagesite.com/hd-stargate-sg1-mobile-phone-wallpaper-1080x1920.htm (before changed the little images to a sprite) (was working previously with display:flex flex:1)

(the following code is part of a div switcher)

Since changing to a sprite ive added the image classes .c1,c2.....

Now im unsure how to get .c5 image to cover the remaining space.

Here it is in a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4wp016Lp/

```
<div class="container-dock">
    <div class="tabs tabs--md">
        <ul class="tabs__list list-unstyled">
            <li class="tabs__item  tabs__item--active">
                                <a href="#tab-1" class="tabs__link">
                <img class="c1"></a> </li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-3" class="tabs__link">
                <img class="c2"></a></li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-2" class="tabs__link"><img class="c3"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-4" class="tabs__link"><img class="c4"></a></li>
            <li class="tabs__item fill">
                <img class="c5">
            </li>
        </ul>
                </div></div>

.container-dock {
  padding: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}


.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4
{background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/dock-cat-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:50px;
height:50px;     
display: inline-block;
}



.c1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.c2 {background-position: 0px -52px;}
.c3 {background-position: 0px -104px;}
.c4 {background-position: 0px -156px;}
.c5 {background-position: 0px -208px;}


.c5{
background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/dock-cat-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;

width:100%; 
height:50px;

}


.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}






@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .tabs--lg {
    border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;


  .tabs--lg .tabs__list {
    background: #0A3D5D;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list .tabs__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list .tabs__item--active {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list--open .tabs__item {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list--open .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #0A3D5D;
    float: right;
    margin-top: .75em;

  }
}

@media (max-width: 1070px) {
  .tabs--xl {
    border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__content {
    border-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list .tabs__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list .tabs__item--active {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list--open .tabs__item {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list--open .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #0A3D5D;
    float: right;
    margin-top: .75em;

  }
}

.tabs__list {

margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;

background: #0A3D5D;

display: flex; /* Added */
}




.tabs__item {
padding-left:1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}



.tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
  border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  background: #0A3D5D;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #333333;

}
.tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
  color: #262626;
}

.tabs__link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333333;
  padding: .0em 0em;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}
.tabs__link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.fill{
width:100%; 
height:50px;
}
```

Comment: try background-size: cover; on the c5 class.

Comment: Well it sort of works. It fills the space but seems to have the c1 image there instead which is very weird.

Comment: @Techagesite You're using the same image for each background image (http://www.techagesite.com/dock-cat-sprite.png). If you're using `background-size:cover;` it covers the space with this image which also contains the c1 image. You could split your image into 5 parts and then `background-size:cover;` will work.

Comment: Is there no way around it using a sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css using border radius and use a square background image without the rounded corners. I would recommend using square background images and border-radius for all of your menu icons.

`.tabs__item.fill > img {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}`

[image]

```css
.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4
{background-image: url('http://www.techagesite.com/dock-cat-sprite.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:50px;
height:50px;     
display: inline-block;
}



.c1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.c2 {background-position: 0px -52px;}
.c3 {background-position: 0px -104px;}
.c4 {background-position: 0px -156px;}
.c5 {background-position: 0px -208px;}


.c5{
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB5jx.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;

width:100%; 
height:50px;

}


.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}






@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .tabs--lg {
    border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;


  .tabs--lg .tabs__list {
    background: #0A3D5D;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list .tabs__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list .tabs__item--active {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list--open .tabs__item {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list--open .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #0A3D5D;
    float: right;
    margin-top: .75em;

  }
}

@media (max-width: 1070px) {
  .tabs--xl {
    border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__content {
    border-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list .tabs__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list .tabs__item--active {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list--open .tabs__item {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list--open .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #0A3D5D;
    float: right;
    margin-top: .75em;

  }
}

.tabs__list {

margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;

background: #0A3D5D;

display: flex; /* Added */
}




.tabs__item {
padding-left:1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}



.tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
  border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  background: #0A3D5D;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #333333;

}
.tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
  color: #262626;
}

.tabs__link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333333;
  padding: .0em 0em;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}
.tabs__link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.fill{
width:100%; 
height:50px;
}


.tabs__item.fill > img {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-dock">
    <div class="tabs tabs--md">
        <ul class="tabs__list list-unstyled">
            <li class="tabs__item  tabs__item--active">
                                <a href="#tab-1" class="tabs__link">
                <img class="c1"></a> </li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-3" class="tabs__link">
                <img class="c2"></a></li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-2" class="tabs__link"><img class="c3"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-4" class="tabs__link"><img class="c4"></a></li>
            <li class="tabs__item fill">
                <img class="c5">
            </li>
        </ul>
                </div></div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get rid of the white borders around the images that show up on my mobile browser?

Comment: I used a method of removing the width and height and substituting padding instead.

Comment: So everything is working except the .c5 isn't showing up on my mobile browser.

Comment: Can you provide a link or a fiddle with your updated code? Which mobile browser are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p0ugsus1/ just the standard browser that came with my android galaxy. It doesn't specify what its called

Comment: You had some errors and a lot of duplicate code in your css. I restructured the css to use the mobile styles first and remove duplicate code. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/p0ugsus1/1/ and see if this get you closer to what you need.

Comment: Well the image now shows up but its the same 50px size and not acting as 100% width. Did you change any html or tabs css? What do you mean restructured to use mobile styles first?

Comment: I did change some things. `.tabs__list {display: table; /* instead of flex */ }`, `.tabs__item {display:table-cell; /* instead of inline-block */ }`, changed images to height and width of 50px and removed the padding,  most of your style rules that started with  `.tabs--lg` and `.tabs--xl` were the same and can be consolidated.  By mobile first I mean that the base styles as seen in small screen devices should come first in the stylesheet. Then followed by media queries targeted at progressively larger screens (ex:  `@media screen and (min-width: 990px)` ) to overwrite the small screen styles.

Comment: Ok i see. I was recent;y told to remove display table from my code for a previous issue so i don't feel comfortable using it